# Passing a non static object to static method in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am working angular 4 application and trying to pass the current language to the toLocaleString() method. The method mathoround is static method and doesnt understand this.translation.currentLang.
How do I pass a non static object to static method.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Injectable()
export class ChartHelperService {


    constructor( private translation: TranslateService) { }

    static prepareChartTooltipRow(name: string, value: string, additionalStyle: string): string {
        return '<tr style="background-color: initial;"><td style="text-align:left;' + additionalStyle + '"><b>' + name +
            '</b></td>' +
            '<td style="text-align: right;' + additionalStyle + '">' +
            value +
            '</td></tr>';
    }

    static showCcorYAxis(id: number): boolean {
        return !(window.innerWidth < 992 && id !== 0);
    }

    static mathRound(input: number): string {
        return Math.round(input).toLocaleString(this.translation.currentLang, { maximumFractionDigits: 0 });
    }

}
```

Comment: The real question should probably be - why make this a static function in the first place? But if you would really want to have statics, you could try using ChartHelperService.translation (instead of this, as you do not have a class instance this available in a static function). Probably the actual correct way to do it is to actually pass the translation service instance from the component you're calling this static function from..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simpliy don't try to mix access to static property like working with class instant.

ChartHelperService as static class

```
export class ChartHelperService {

    static translation:TranslateService;

    setTranslationService( translation: TranslateService) {
        ChartHelperService.translation = translation;
    }

    static prepareChartTooltipRow(name: string, value: string, additionalStyle: string): string {
        return '<tr style="background-color: initial;"><td style="text-align:left;' + additionalStyle + '"><b>' + name +
            '</b></td>' +
            '<td style="text-align: right;' + additionalStyle + '">' +
            value +
            '</td></tr>';
    }

    static showCcorYAxis(id: number): boolean {
        return !(window.innerWidth < 992 && id !== 0);
    }

    static mathRound(input: number): string {
        return Math.round(input).toLocaleString(ChartHelperService.translation.currentLang, { maximumFractionDigits: 0 });
    }

}
```

and you can set the translation property on the AppComponent constractor

```
export class AppComponent  {    
  constructor( private translation: TranslateService ) {
   ChartHelperService.setTranslationService(translation);
  }
}
```

> ChartHelperService in utility class so you don't need to add it to provider list

**Updated**

ChartHelperService as Service

```
@Injectable()
export class ChartHelperService {


    constructor( private translation: TranslateService) { }

    public prepareChartTooltipRow (name: string, value: string, additionalStyle: string): string {
        return '<tr style="background-color: initial;"><td style="text-align:left;' + additionalStyle + '"><b>' + name +
            '</b></td>' +
            '<td style="text-align: right;' + additionalStyle + '">' +
            value +
            '</td></tr>';
    }

    public showCcorYAxis(id: number): boolean {
        return !(window.innerWidth < 992 && id !== 0);
    }

    public mathRound(input: number): string {
        return Math.round(input).toLocaleString(this.translation.currentLang, { maximumFractionDigits: 0 });
    }

}
```

In this case you need to add `ChartHelperService` to providers list and inject `ChartHelperService` to any component to get an instant of `ChartHelperService`.

```
export class TestComponent  {    
   constructor( private chartHelperService: ChartHelperService) {
     console.log(this.chartHelperService)
   }
 }
```

Comment: The application does not have appcomponent. It only had appmodule

Comment: you can add constructor on appmodule and set the translation servcie it 's also posible @Tom